# How can use defer field in script template in Sitecore?

Tags: sitecore

I am using script template.In this template there is two field source and defer.I have created js folder inside content, inside that i have used script template and in server side i am getting source field and bind it .But i am not able to find how I can use defer field. Can anybody guide me?

[image]

Comment: How are you rendering this in your code? Personally I would be wary of using this template since it's a Sitecore System template. Note the `server file` field type is also deprecated. If you give example of what you want to achieve then may be able to help further, with some code samples.

Comment: As you mentioned server file is deprecated so what can be other option? I want to add multiple script and javascript  file using code.

Comment: I saw this link https://webcmd.wordpress.com/2010/10/26/building-a-sitecore-base-page-template/ but it is writing script using response.write and i do not want to use this.

Comment: As @jammykam said you need to rethink, what are your requirements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, I don't use any of the System templates in my own code and given that this template uses a field marked deprecated I would be even less inclined to use it since Sitecore may change or remove it completely in future releases. The field seems quite handy in being able to select files directly from the file system, but also quite dangerous in also allowing users to upload files directly as well. Even more reason not to use this field in my opinion, javascript and css is not your everyday content editor activity.

There are no  controls that I know of that will render this field type either that I know of, you will need to handle it yourself.

1. Create a new template to represent your script. You can use a `Single-Line Text` and `Checkbox` fields.

[image: Script Template]

2. Create items from the template. Restrict permissions to developers/power users only. You have to enter the exact path yourself. The deprecated `server file` field stores the underlying data as text anyway.

[image: Script Items]

3. Get the items, loop through them and render on your front-end.

You can use code similar to this. I've assumed you're using Webforms from your previous posts:

**User Control.ascx**

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptScripts" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptScripts_ItemDataBound" >
    <ItemTemplate>              
        <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="litInclude" />
    </ItemTemplate> 
</asp:Repeater>
```

**Codebehind:**

```
private const string script = "<script src=\"{0}\" {1}></script>";
private const string styles = "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"{0}\">";

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var items = Sitecore.Context.Database.SelectItems("/sitecore/content/path/to/scripts/*");
    rptScripts.DataSource = items;
    rptScripts.DataBind();
}

protected void rptScripts_ItemDataBound(object Sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        var item = (Sitecore.Data.Items.Item)e.Item.DataItem;
        var ctrl = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.Literal)e.Item.FindControl("litInclude");
        ctrl.Text = GetMarkup(item);
    }
}

private string GetMarkup(Sitecore.Data.Items.Item item)
{
    if (item.TemplateName == "Javascript")
    {
        string defer = (MainUtil.GetBool(item["Defer"], false)) ? "defer" : string.empty;
        return script.FormatWith(item["Source"], defer);        
    }
    else if (item.TemplateName == "Stylesheet")
    {
        return styles.FormatWith(item["Source"]);
    }
    return string.empty;
}
```

You would be better creating bundles, or to create theme packs (sets of javascripts and css) which the user can select using a droplink field. This will give the user flexibility to select different styling but keeping everything within brand guidelines.